# How to add mobile number to blackberry contact editor in programatically from my blackberry application?

Tags: blackberry, java-me, mobile, contacts

I am developing one application in that i have contact details ,when i click the contact number it will ask some option like call or sms or add to phone contact. I implemented call and sms, But when am trying to implement add number ,name ,email in to the phone contact am getting struggle. the below code am used for add contact

```
 try 
         {
               ContactList contacts = null;
               try {
                  contacts = (ContactList) PIM.getInstance().openPIMList(PIM.CONTACT_LIST, PIM.READ_WRITE);
               } catch (PIMException e) {
                  // An error occurred
                  return;
               }
               Contact contact = contacts.createContact();


              String[] name = new String[ contacts.stringArraySize( Contact.NAME) ];
              name[Contact.NAME_GIVEN] = "Kate";
              name[Contact.NAME_FAMILY] = "Turner";


              contact.addStringArray(Contact.NAME, Contact.ATTR_NONE,name);
              contact.addString(Contact.EMAIL, Contact.ATTR_NONE, emailAddressTo);
             contact.addString(Contact.TEL,Contact.ATTR_NONE,"6776787"//this for voice call number.
              AddressBookArguments entry = new AddressBookArguments(AddressBookArguments.ARG_NEW, contact);

              Invoke.invokeApplication(Invoke.APP_TYPE_ADDRESSBOOK, entry);

         } 
         catch (Throwable t)
         {
         }

     }
```

This above code work fine but when am trying to add mobile number like this

```
contact.addString(Contact.ATTR_MOBILE,Contact.ATTR_NONE,"mobile Number");
```

am getting exception Illegal argument Exception, I don't know how to add the mobile number here,Can anyone help me to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this,

```
if (contacts.isSupportedField(Contact.TEL)) {
 contact.addString(Contact.TEL, Contact.ATTR_MOBILE, "1234567890");
}
```

See this IBM developerWorks article for more info:
[Develop mobile apps with Personal Information Management](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/tutorials/wi-pim/section3.html)